# Replicating new Google Play Music's ListView

Tags: android, material-design

A new, refreshed Google Play Music app has been out on the Play Store for a while now. It brought additions to GPM's already awesome UI such as full-height navigation drawer, proper CardView for albums and many more.

The biggest wow-factor for me, though, is their ListView. Take a look at this:

[image: GPM's awesome ListView]

It looks **incredibly** good. Instead creating every list item as a card of their own (which is discouraged by the guideline) they made the entire list as one entity - as a single card. Brilliant.

Now come the ultimate question: How could we replicate it? This doesnt look like an ordinary ListView to me. Especially because of the orange background scrolls parallaxly. Is it possible that they used ordinary LinearLayout combined with ScrollView?

Can somebody enlighten me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever workout how they did this?